# Парсинг html при помощи JSOUP. Не могу достать значение

Tags: android, html, парсер, jsoup

Не могу достать одно значение, хотя перепробовал различные вариации [СЕЛЕКТОРОВ](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)
Интересует следующий кусок `html` разметки:

```
<div class="post">
<div style="float:left;">
<a href="URL_1" rel="bookmark">
<img src="URL_2" alt="TEXT" class="thumbnail" />
</a>
</div>  
</div>
```

Нужно достать значение URL_2. Мой кусок кода такой:

```
Element element = doc.select(".post XXX a img").first();
model.setUrl_2(element.attr("abs:src"));
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что мне нужно написать вместо XXX. Не понимаю.

Comment: Я бы написал `div.post div a img`. Должно быть достаточно.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл такое решение на мой вопрос:

```
Element element = doc.select(".post div[style] a img").first();
```